# Is the intersection of two wedge-shaped regions also wedge-shaped?

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, inequality, analytic-geometry, plane-geometry

In the plane $\mathbb{R}^2$, the intersection of two wedge-shaped regions should still be wedge-shaped.

[image: The two triangular regions intersection]

However I don't see where to go from here. I searched for wedge-shaped and couldn't find anything on SE. If I write a wedge-shaped region as $y > ax+b$ and $y> cx + d$ where $a,c$ are both non-zero, how do I write the intersection of two such regions in the same form? Is this a linear algebra question?

Comment: A "cone" is a three-dimensional figure.  A wedge is two-dimensional, as appropriate here.  I changed your title accordingly.

Comment: I'll bet the edit wars they have on wikipedia are nothing compared to this site. You changed my title! ;_;

Answer (score 1):

It depends on how restrictive your definition of cone is, but in almost any case I can think of the answer is generally that "cone-ness" is not preserved under intersection. Indeed, imagine in your example if the orange and blue cones were very narrow and wide (resp.). It's then possible that their intersection doesn't emanate from a single vertex. I made a (bad) illustration of this [here](http://ggbtu.be/m2734211). (Sorry, I'm new to Geogebra.)

Even if the intersection is a new cone in the form you want, you can (referring to the cones in your picture) solve for the equation of the line bounding the orange cone with positive slope and that bounding the blue cone with negative slope. If those lines are $y = ax+b$ and $y = cx+d$, then the desired cone is of the form $y > a x + b$ and $y > c x + d$.

Comment: Thanks, is geogebra the best program you've found for doing plane geometry? There's another one called Cinderella and maybe a few others.

Comment: @SerPolybius: No problem! And I wasn't aware of Cinderella but will check it out! I rarely find myself in need of this sort of application, and this is the first time I've made something with Geogebra. It's a convenient option due to its price ($0) and ease of sharing graphs. During my undergrad, I believe the math dept. had Geometer's Sketchpad installed on its lab computers, and I played with that a bit. (It's really nice, albeit not free or online last time I checked.)

Answer (score 0):

If a *cone-shaped region* is one of the four "pieces" (connected components) of the complement of two lines in the plane, i.e., the convex region defined by two non-parallel rays, then:

- The intersection of two cone-shaped regions is ("usually") not cone-shaped. Even if "both regions open in the same direction", the rays defining one region may intersect *both* rays defining the other. (This is the case in the diagram provided: The left-hand ray of the blue cone hits both rays of the orange cone if you continue the picture far enough up and to the left.)
- If each ray of one cone-shaped region is parallel to a ray of the other, then yes, the intersection is a cone-shaped region.

Comment: Yes the image I had in my head was of the rays being parallel to each other. For example, both left slopes being the same as both right slopes. if I want to add this information should I edit the original question or post an answer? Should I post an algebraic solution?

Comment: Under the circumstances I think it's fair to edit to question to add the additional constraint. (It's frowned upon to make substantial, meaning-changing edits to a question that's been answered, but that's not what you'd be doing.) It would also be fine to post an algebraic solution as an answer if Dan's answer doesn't already contain the algebraic details you consider definitive. :)